# Java App Engine sessions without cookies

Tags: google-app-engine

On App Engine (Java runtime) is it possible to use sessions without the JSESSIONID cookie? For example, Tomcat will rewrite the URL with a JSESSIONID at the end if it detects cookies aren't supported. Does the app engine java runtime support this or a similar mechanism?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no built-in support for putting the session id in the URL, but nothing we do prevents you doing this yourself.